# Extract Id from Twitch Clip URL

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can I extract the Id of a Twitch Clip URL.

Example:

```
https://clips.twitch.tv/KindYummyCarrotPeteZaroll?some=1
```

I need only the Id part, for example: `https://clips.twitch.tv/[ID]?v=1`

The Id in the top example is `KindYummyCarrotPeteZaroll`. Any query string if comes after should be ignored and not be part of the Id.

I tried:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(url, @"^(https://clips\.twitch\.tv/)(?:(?!http).)*?");
```

But I wasn't able to capture the Id in a group. I am using ASP.NET and C#.

Comment: Try `(?<=twitch.tv/)(\w*)(?=\?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for Regex:

```
string str = "https://clips.twitch.tv/KindYummyCarrotPeteZaroll?some=1";
string id = str.Split('/', '?')[3];
```